# PHP - Submit button and Modal Pop-up AJAX on 2 browsers PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am new to php AJAX coding, my problem is I have TWO BROWSERS, first is I want to click the submit button and after that I want a modal to popup on the other browser so the final output will be a 2 browsers. just like a chat system. but it is different because I only want a button and a pop up modal.

> so for example here is my button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">CLICK TO POPUP</button>
```

> My Modal

```
 <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I popup this modal to the other localhost browser

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent snapshots with php socket, you can run the results in all open windows.

[PHP Socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

[WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Hello there, can i ask what is the difference of both?

Comment: I cant understand you sorry

Answer (score 0):

First, we are writing the listener in a php file.
then it writes a javascript process that will get the listener to tap and get feedback.
I'm sending the socket e 'getOpenPopUp' message that we're connected to with javascript. The socket on the php side is sending the `openPopUp` message to all clients after verifying it. this message is received on the javascript side popUp opens. my English is not good at all. I'm sorry I couldn't tell.

`socket.php` - `Ratchet Class` [Ratchet](http://socketo.me)

```
<?php
    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;


use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;


class Application implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }


    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        if ( $msg === 'getOpenPopUp' ) {
            foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
                $client->send('openPopUp');
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {

    }
}


$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Application()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

`App.js` - `WebSocket` [MDN Writing WebSocket client applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
var button = document.getElementById('button');


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click')
    socket.send('getOpenPopUp');
});


socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    if ( e.data === 'openPopUp' ) {
        UIkit.modal.confirm('UIkit confirm!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method is also controlled by ajax, which records the operation in a database every second, and popUp is shown with data from ajax if it needs to be shown in popUp.

**But not a highly recommended method**

Click Button

```
$.ajax({ url: "saveClickButton.php" })

setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'isClickButton' }).done(function(data) {
      if ( data === "true" ) {
          // Open Pop Up
      }
    });
}, 1000)
```